# Richtext Redactor Field - Standard Layout does not show image button

Tags: redactor, image, richtext

When i use a "Default" Richtext field - the image button displays and works.
When i change Default to "Standard" (the out of the box one) the image button does not display.

All instructions suggest Craft should be handling this to map asset fields to the richtext field. But it is failing for these - Any ideas?

Comment: What does your config file look like?

Answer (score 1):

Tested and it works fine for me locally with the stock `Standard.json` config of

```
{
    buttons: ['html','formatting','bold','italic','unorderedlist','orderedlist','link','image','video'],
    plugins: ['fullscreen','video'],
    toolbarFixed: true
}
```

I'd make sure you don't have any other plugins installed that might be interfering and that you've actually got the `'image'` value listed under your `buttons:` key.